# cannot add selected attribute to ion-option

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I cannot find out the problem that how I cannot add selected attribute to get default selected property on ion-option

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-label>example</ion-label>
            <ion-select 
            [selectOptions]="selectOptionsEducation" 
            [(ngModel)]="filterData.education"
            multiple="true" placeholder="Class 10">
                <ion-option value="class 11" selected="true">Class 11</ion-option>
                <ion-option [selected]="true" value="class 12">Class 12</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="graduation">Graduation</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add selected attribute in ion-option to make the option selected

To get auto select the ion-option you need to pass the value of ion-option in the [(ngModel)] variable.

```
//page.ts

filterData = {
  education = ['graduation']
}


//page.html

<ion-list>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-label>example</ion-label>
            <ion-select 

            [(ngModel)]="filterData.education"
            multiple="true" placeholder="Class 10">
                <ion-option value="class 11" >Class 11</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="class 12">Class 12</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="graduation">Graduation</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you want actually. But,

1.If you are trying to default selection on option number 2 then remove square brackets `[]` and simply set

```html
<ion-option selected="true" value="class 12">Class 12</ion-option>
```

as setted in option number 1.

Or just set

```html
<ion-option selected value="class 12">Class 12</ion-option>
```

2. If you want to dynamic changes on your `ion-option` selection, then create a global variable in your.ts file and then you can use that variable in component to dynamic selection like :

```html
<ion-option [selected]="class12Selected" value="class 12">Class 12</ion-option>
```

Comment: This method will not work for multiple select options for sure.